# Using mapActions correctly with nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxtjs

I need to use mapActions in a nuxt.js store.

If I call the "dispatch" method all is ok, but when I use the mapActions I get 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' error.

// storequiz.js

```
export const state = () => ({
  quizVersion: null,
  stage: null,
  title: null,
  img: null,
  questions: [],
  currentQuestion: null,
  answers: [],
})

export const mutations = {
  setQuizVersion(state, version) {
    state.quizVersion = version
  },
  setQuestions(state, questions) {
    state.questions = questions
  },
  
}

export const actions = {
  async fetchData({ commit }, payload) {
    const res = await this.$axios.get(payload)
    commit('setQuizVersion', res.data.version)
    commit('setQuestions', res.data.questions)
  },
}
```

// my methods:

```
methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      fetchData: 'storequiz/fetchData',
     }),
    async fetchData() {
      // await this.$store.dispatch('storequiz/fetchData', this.url)
      await this.fetchData(this.url)
    },
....
```

I am getting the error:

```
error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
client.js?06a0:103 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at new Context (runtime.js?96cf:449)
    at Object.wrap (runtime.js?96cf:41)
    at _callee2 (Quiz.vue?b7d7:182)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:22)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:21)
    at VueComponent.fetchData (Quiz.vue?b7d7:182)
    at _callee2$ (Quiz.vue?b7d7:182)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:293)
```

If I use: `await this.$store.dispatch('storequiz/fetchData', this.url)`
instead of `await this.fetchData(this.url)`, all works well.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapped `fetchData` is hidden by the subsequent method of the same name. You should rename one of them for unique method names (if they're both needed).

Also, the component method `fetchData` calls itself unconditionally, so there's an infinite loop that would lead to the `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Add a condition to break out of the loop (if this call is even needed).